# Add hyperlink to a slide in the current PowerPoint

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I've been searching for this for hours, but could not find appropriate approach to do so. On MSDN, they suggest using `Address` and `SubAddress` to locate a slide in a Presentation, but this failed its purpose.

So my question is, how to add a hyperlink to a slide in the same Presentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I've figured it out, and since there's lack of resources, I would like to post my solution.

Interestingly, to add a hyperlink to a slide inside the same presentation, you need to leave `Address` property blank, and set its `SubAddress` to be a string in a format: "yourSlideID,yourSlideIndex,yourSlideName".

For example, you want to add a hyperlink to a slide with **slide ID 256, slide index 1, slide name "Slide 1"**, to a shape, do this:

```
var mouseOnClickAction = shape.ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick];

mouseOnClickAction.Action = PpActionType.ppActionNamedSlideShow;
mouseOnClickAction.Hyperlink.Address = null;
mouseOnClickAction.Hyperlink.SubAddress = "256,1,Slide 1";
```

Hope this helps everybody :D

Comment: The last parameter should actually be the slide's title, if any, not the slide name;  if the slide has no title, then "Slide x" where x is the slide index at the time the link is created. IIRC, you can leave it out if you like; and if the slide title has a comma in it, the link is liable to break in at least some versions of PPT.  The Slide ID is the critical bit: the slide can be moved around in the presentation (SlideIndex changes) or the title edited, which would invalidate the second and third parms; SlideID never changes, so that's really what the link depends on.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg thanks for your comment, but I've tried out on my application and turned out that the last parameter should be the name of the slide, i.e. the one you get from `Slide.Name`. It's different from the one you see when you manually add the link, that one shows the slide's title. In my application, I used slide.Id + "," + slide.Index + "," + slide.Name to generate that SubAddress, and it worked.